# declaring non-register variables using asm in gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly

The following code compiles with gcc:

```
// at global scope
int rslt[1] asm("RSLT");
```

The generated assembly code uses the `RSLT` symbol for the variable instead of `rslt`.

How does this work, and why/when would you use it?

Comment: [asm labels in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html). EDIT: third time is the charm! LOL.

Comment: assembly language both real and inline are tool specific not just target, so what target is this for and what version of gcc, and what did you find when you went to the gnu website and looked this up?

Comment: assembly doesnt have variables generally, instead this may be generating a label, can you post the code generated by the compiler?

Comment: @Jester: You should post that as an answer (but give a bite more information than just the link).

Comment: @old_timer: this only works for functions, or variables with static storage-class, which *do* have a symbol name in asm.  I've updated the question to not make an off-topic request for doc links, and instead to directly ask how it works.

Comment: @Jester: Thanks. That's the information I was looking for.